# Allocated Memory not freeing up

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, cifilter

I started a project yesterday to see how different CIFilters work. I've got everything working but what I noticed was that with each use of a new filter my application memory spikes up. until now i've seen the memory go up to 80mb... which is way too much for something as simple as what I'm trying to do... There must be some objects that I'm allocating but they are not getting de-allocated. I am using an ARC app with xCode 5.1.1

here is the code

```
-(UIImage *)filteredImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image andFilter:(CIFilter *)filter
{
    /* Create a CIImage using the property on UIImage, CGImage. */
    CIImage *unfilteredImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage];

    /* Set the filter with the unfiltered CIImage for key kCIInputImageKey */
    [filter setValue:unfilteredImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    /* Get the filtered image back calling the method outputImage */
    CIImage *filteredImage = [filter outputImage];


    return [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filteredImage];

}

- (CIFilter *)filterAtIndex:(int)index
{
    CIFilter *filter = nil;
    switch (index) {
        case 0: // Blur

            filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues: nil];

            break;
        case 1: // Sepia

            filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues:nil];

            break;
        case 2: // Monochrome

            filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues: nil];

            break;
        case 3: // Color Invert

            filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert" keysAndValues:nil];

            break;
        case 4: // False Color

            filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor" keysAndValues: nil];

            break;
        case 5: // Posterize

            filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorPosterize" keysAndValues:nil];

            break;

        default:

            break;
    }

    return filter;

}
```

This is not my code... I picked it from the web... made some changes... but i've searched a lot and can't find the original...

Can anyone help me figure out why this code create a lot of un released memory.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Using for example an 8 Megapixel photo and using it in a filter may be simple, doesn't mean it doesn't take lots of memory.

Comment: true.. but if i load an image it should take up its memory and then stay there... it shouldn't keep eating more memory as I start applying filters, right?... e.g when i load the image the app's mem is at 18mb then i call filteredImageFromImage:andFilter once and the men jumps to 40+mb the next time i call it, it jumps to 50+ ... that is what I'm trying to figure out here....

Comment: You're doing a [CIImage alloc] and I'm wondering if you need to set that to nil after you are done with it. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yup, that was the first thing I tried... didn't work... ARC should automatically release unfilteredImage anyway as soon as we move out of the scope of the method... I think thats why setting it to nil didn't work.